# mysql CASE WHEN : case order and logic

Tags: mysql

Given a table, BST, containing two columns: N and P, where N represents the value of a node in Binary Tree, and P is the parent of N.

Write a query to find the node type of Binary Tree ordered by the value of the node. Output one of the following for each node:

- Root: If node is root node.
- Leaf: If node is leaf node.
- Inner: If node is neither root nor leaf node.

Sample below has 7 nodes:
[image]

[image]

The test table has 15 nodes.
My query is:

```
SELECT n, 
CASE 
    WHEN n NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT P FROM BST) THEN 'leaf'
    WHEN p IS NULL THEN 'root'
    ELSE 'inner'
END 
FROM BST
ORDER BY N;
```

Query result (Unexpected):

[image]
[image]

The correct query looks like this:

```
SELECT n, 
CASE
    WHEN P IS NULL THEN ' Root'
    WHEN N IN (SELECT DISTINCT P FROM BST) THEN ' Inner'
    ELSE ' Leaf'
    END
FROM BST
ORDER BY N;
```

Query result:

[image]
[image]

Can you explain how these queries work, and why they do not work like the if-else statements in other languages？

Comment: Remove pictures. Add sample data as CREATE TABLE +INSERT INTO, code-formatted text (decrease the rows amount, 4-5 rows will be enough). Show the outputs as formatted textual table. Outputs must match shown sample data completely.

Comment: @DavidZayn Please provide the full picture of binary tree. These are called hierarchical data, so it is handled differently.Maybe you should change the question header differently like''hierarchical data(root-leaf-node) in mysql.